# problem unmarshalling xml doc to Java objects (jaxb)

Tags: xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, unmarshalling

I've used xjc to create java objects from XSD.

and now I am trying to unmarshal the xml doc to the java objects but I get:

`javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"GlobalComponentInformation`

Any here here?

EDIT:

I am passing a org.w3c.dom.Document object, it returned from a web service call (axis web service)...

Note, the Document object returned from ws to be parsed here contains the following root element:

```
<GlobalInformationResponseDocument xmlns="" />
```

@XmlRootElement class looks like:

```
XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "wsExternalResponse"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GlobalInformationResponseDocument")
public class GlobalInformationResponseDocument {

    @XmlElement(name = "WS_ExternalResponse", required = true)
    protected WSExternalResponseType wsExternalResponse;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the wsExternalResponse property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link WSExternalResponseType }
     *     
     */
    public WSExternalResponseType getWSExternalResponse() {
        return wsExternalResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the wsExternalResponse property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link WSExternalResponseType }
     *     
     */
    public void setWSExternalResponse(WSExternalResponseType value) {
        this.wsExternalResponse = value;
    }

}
```

package-info:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/GlobalInformationResponseExt", 
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.company.jaxb.client;
```

Comment: What does the @XmlRootElement on your root class look like?  Also what does your package-info class look like (if you have one)?  Also what kind of XML input are you unmarshalling (stream, DOM, etc)?

Comment: Where does GlobalComponentInformation come in? It is probably returned in your XML-response which is parsed? Did you not define it in the XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root element you are receiving from the web service class:

```
<GlobalInformationResponseDocument xmlns="" />
```

Does not match the expected root element that is expected based on your JAXB mappings:

```
<GlobalInformationResponseDocument xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/GlobalInformationResponseExt" />
```

The package-info class specifies that all elements should be namespace qualified (javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED), and that the default namespace is 
*"http://www.mycompany.com/GlobalInformationResponseExt"*

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/GlobalInformationResponseExt", 
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.company.jaxb.client;
```

You will either need to fix the XML document, or change the JAXB mappings to match the documnent.  In this case by removing package-info.

Comment: I did changed the xml document, and then passed to JAXB marshal object that doesn't accept the modified object unless I convert the doc to string then to doc!

Comment: What did you do when you "changed the xml document"?  Since converting the doc to a string and back to a doc works, I'm assuming the your change did not correctly address the namespace mismatch.